# Confluence Export to Kentico Import

Tags: kentico

We have 70 pages of documentation in Confluence that I need to get into my Page Tree in Kentico v11.

Is it possible to use the import toolkit to import the exported xml file? Is there another way I should be thinking of doing this? I know in Confluence you can subscribe to rss. I am wondering if maybe  repeater and rss datasource may be the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're able to export this into an XML file, you can use the Kentico Import Toolkit (KIT) to import the XML file into a node in the content tree.  My guess is your page type may only have 2 fields in it: PageName, PageContent.  Your PageContent field would need to be rich text to allow for any HTML formatting.